# Assign/Deserialize generic object with more derived type into the one with less derived type

Tags: c#, generics, json.net, covariance

I have a class with the following structure

```
public class GenericEntity<T>
    where T : BaseClass
{
    T Property {get; set;}
}
```

I have several concrete implementations of `BaseClass` and am using those concrete implementations to instantiate object of type `GenericEntity`

e.g. `var entity = new GenericEntity<DerivedClass>()`

I am pushing this entity into a messaging framework by serializing the object into JSON (using Newtonsoft). At the other end, I am extracting that message (JSON) from messaging queue and am trying to deserialize message into type `GenericEntity<BaseClass>`, with JsonSerializerSettings `TypeNameHandling.All`. But at the time of deserialization, it throws `JsonSerializationException` with details

> Type specified in JSON 'NewtonsoftPlayground.GenericEntity`1[[NewtonsoftPlayground.DerivedClass, NewtonsoftPlayground, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], NewtonsoftPlayground, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not compatible with 'NewtonsoftPlayground.GenericEntity`1[[NewtonsoftPlayground.BaseClass, NewtonsoftPlayground, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], NewtonsoftPlayground, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

How can I achieve this? Or should I not use generic? If so, I would end up writing type casts everywhere after extracting message from queue, which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any straight forward solution to achieve this. As @Tamas Ionut suggested, specifying base class while deserializing will not deserialize properties of concrete class.

As a workaround, I've created a static method which basically instantiates `GenericEntity<BaseClass>` and copies all properties in it using reflection.

```
    public static GenericEntity<BaseClass> ConvertToBaseEntity(object model)
    {
        if (model.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(GenericEntity<>))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Model should be of type GenericEntity<T>.", "model");
        }

        GenericEntity<BaseClass> baseModel = new GenericEntity<BaseClass>();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in model.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            baseModel.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).SetValue(baseModel, propertyInfo.GetValue(model));
        }

        return baseModel;
    }
```

I hope, this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following code recreated:

```
public class GenericEntity<T> where T : BaseClass 
    {
   public T Property { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass {
}

class Derived1 : BaseClass
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Derived2 : BaseClass {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

....

static void Main()
    {
        Derived1 d1 = new Derived1 {Age = 23};
        GenericEntity<Derived1> entity = new GenericEntity<Derived1> {Property = d1};

        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity, new JsonSerializerSettings() {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        });
        var baseEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, typeof(GenericEntity<BaseClass>));
}
```

I get no errors while deserializing the data. Let me know on your context and how it differs.

This will obviously not work:

```
        BaseClass d1 = new Derived1 {Age = 23};
        GenericEntity<BaseClass> entity = new GenericEntity<BaseClass> {Property = d1};

        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity, new JsonSerializerSettings() {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        });
        var baseEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericEntity<Derived1>>(data, new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        });
```

If you serialize a BaseClass, it will not be responsible of serializing all the extra details that the specialized class has (I mean, you wanted to serialize a BaseClass and that is exactly what you will serialize).

It is your job to serialize them as specialized instances: that is if you get a BaseClass and you know you need a Derived1 parse that instance as Derived1 and then serialize it.

Comment: Hi @Tamas Ionut, if you will use `TypeNameHandling.All` settings while serialization, you'll get the error. In the code you tried, it's deserializing object to base class, but derived class property values are missed. What I am trying to achieve is, deserialized instance should be of type `Derived1`, but the interface should be of type `BaseClass`. I hope this clears further. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with you. I am serializing specialized class only. I am serializing instance of type `GenericEntity<Derived1>`, but at time of deserialization I want it to be `GenericEntity<BaseClass>` holding instance of type `GenericEntity<DerivedClass>`.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this: ` Derived1 d1 = new Derived1 { Age = 23 };
            GenericEntity<Derived1> entity = new GenericEntity<Derived1> { Property = d1 };

            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity, new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
            });
            var baseEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericEntity<BaseClass>>(data, new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
            });`

Comment: This is still problematic, since you specify GenericEntity<BaseClass> for deserialization you'll get what you've asked for. You can try the non-generic version of the Deserialize by specifying the concrete type (edited the answer). This is for the case when you don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: Gotcha. Even using non-generic method with `typeof(GenericEntity<BaseClass>)` parameter throws non-compatible type exception. Have got a workaround using reflection. Am posting my solution as an answer below.

Comment: Yes, you have to specify the specific type as well. That workaround will definitely work, but you may want to think a bit on your design, since if you need to go via reflection, there may be some design/abstractization flaws which you need to reconsider